# boost::unit_test case fails because a child process exits with nonzero

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have the following code:

```
bool f()
{
  command = "mkdir -p /\/\/";
  result = aSystemCall(command);
  if (result == ...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(BadDir)
{
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(false, f());
}
```

If I execute `command` in command line, I get a permission denied error. I'm aware of this. That's exactly what I want to test.
`aSystemCall` executes the command as a child process. As the child exits with a nonzero error for this command, `aSystemCall` returns an error. It doesn't throw.
If I run `BadDir` test case in command line, the code after `aSystemCall` is never executed, and the test fails, with the following output:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/\/\/': Permission denied
unknown location(0): fatal error in "BadDir": child has exited; pid: 25356; uid: 19753;   exit value: 1
test.cpp(100): last checkpoint
Leaving test case "BadDir"; testing time: 10ms
Leaving test suite "Test"
Leaving test suite "Master Test Suite"
```

If I run `BadDir` test case within gdb, `aSystemCall` returns, the result can be checked, and the test passes.

Is there a way to telling boost::unit_test to filter out possible errors like this one, so that execution can continue? I've tried `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_EXPECTED_FAILURE(blah, 1)`, but this is just to tell boost::unit_test that you are expecting a failure. It reports failure detected (failure expected) in test. I would like a passed test situation instead.

Comment: Does the aSystemCall return, or throw an exception?

Comment: Side-note: To check for boolean values, use `BOOST_CHECK` instead of `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL`. It's more concise.

Comment: If the test passes in the debugger, *what* doesn't work when running the test normally? Maybe provide the error output from Boost.Test.

Comment: @Arafangion - aSystemCall spanws a new process, which exits with nonzero. But the parent process just returns an error code.
@Space_C0wb0y - Doesn't BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL gives you output information of the kind false=...?
@Martin - I think boost just complains of a child process exiting with a nonzero code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved in later version of Boost.Test

Comment: Thanks Gennadiy, always good knowing first hand from a boost developer :) So I understand there is no way of achieving what I want with the current boost test implementation.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "current". This is resolved several boost releases ago. 
If you are talking about your local verison, and you have boost sources, you can disable SIGCHLD handler in execution monitor yourself.

Comment: OK, I had understood "This is resolved in an upcoming version of Boost.Test". I am using 1.44. Is disabling SIGCHLD the only way of getting the behaviour I expect?

Comment: This answer is not well explained.

Comment: @Gennadiy I got the expected behaviour using '#define BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_NON_ZERO_CHILD_CODE' before the unit_test.hpp include. Is that flag, and others, defined somewhere within boost test doc? Can you def/undef that for a test, or just for a whole run?

Comment: @rturrado BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_NON_ZERO_CHILD_CODE should work, but I pretty sure SIGCHLD handler disabled completely in trunk for quite some time. There is small chance I did not move the changes into the release brunch. I'll follow up.

Comment: @Gennadiy Setting this answer as my accepted answer, but I would appreciate a more detailed explanation from your side, and the outcome of your follow up.

Answer (score 4):

First of all i get this odd behavior only on Linux.

I've found that *Boost.Test* changes the way it handles child exit codes with the deploy model you choose. 
If you are using static linking of boost libraries or the "all in one" header `boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp` inserting a define:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_NON_ZERO_CHILD_CODE
```

before any include directive solves the problem.

If you are using dynamic linking, this isn't enough. You have either to call the resulting test with the command line option *"--catch_system_errors=no"* or define the following environment variable.

```
export BOOST_TEST_CATCH_SYSTEM_ERRORS="no"
```

I'm using boost 1.52 and 1.57, GCC 4.7.2, on a debian wheezy.

Here is the reference to [deploy models of Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/usage-variants.html)

see also this question: [how-to-cancel-fatal-error-detection-in-boost-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083323/how-to-cancel-fatal-error-detection-in-boost-test)

Comment: This does not appear to work on Boost 1.55. `--catch_system_errors=no` does appear to work, as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding --catch_system_errors=no at run-time also works.

I would prefer to be able to handle this with a a macro similar to BOOST_CHECK_THROW or a #define that doesn't require recompiling unit_test, but at least there's a solution in place.

Comment: This does appear to work on Boost 1.55, `#define BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_NON_ZERO_CHILD_CODE` as mentioned in another answer doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Unfortunately only when linking staticly

Answer (score 0):

If you run your test from terminal you should set to "no" Boost environment variable *catch_system_errors*. 
In case Ubuntu OS, you have to type next command in terminal before test execution:

```
export BOOST_TEST_CATCH_SYSTEM_ERRORS="no"
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on Chip Christian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7012502/678022): (re)compiling boost.test with the BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_NON_ZERO_CHILD_CODE flag works (tested for boost 1.53). On the bjam command line, add:

```
cxxflags="-DBOOST_TEST_IGNORE_NON_ZERO_CHILD_CODE"
```

Note that adding this flag did not always seem to force a recompile, so I did the following to force recompiling:

```
touch boost/test/impl/execution_monitor.ipp
```