# How to cancel "fatal error" detection in BOOST TEST

Tags: c++, boost-test

I get an error: `unknown location(0): fatal error in "suite_1_test_1": child has exited; pid: 5817; uid: 0; exit value: 255`

Inside `suite_1_test_1` I run a program `A` with `execvp()` (after `fork()`), which may be exit with an error code that is not `0`. this error code indicates what happened to program `A`.

The problem is that, if I get this `fatal error`, I can't handle the `exit()` value, and the `BOOST TEST` gets out immediately.

Can I somehow turn it off for a moment?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean by that "How to find and fix an unknown yet bug?"?

Comment: No, I mean "How to shut down fatal error detection" or something like that...

Comment: Linux, RedHat, Why does it matter?
I wanted ask if there is some command in the BOOST TEST code which let me do that

Comment: If you don't care about the test results, why run the test?

Comment: I care about the tests results, but I want to handle them my own way, and that is - without getting out of the test_case... just by declaring an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is possible to do so:

[boost::unit_test case fails because a child process exits with nonzero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325202/boostunit-test-case-fails-because-a-child-process-exits-with-nonzero)

just do
`#define BOOST_TEST_IGNORE_NON_ZERO_CHILD_CODE`
before the
`#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE aot_test_module`
in the `main()`

When using shared libraries, run with command line option `--catch_system_errors=no` or `export BOOST_TEST_CATCH_SYSTEM_ERRORS=“no”`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that boost registers signal handlers or other stuff, that still catch errors from the forked (and overridden) process. You will have a hard time "unhooking" the test framework from that child process.

However, unit test frameworks are seldom meant to be used together with the spawning of child processes, so I would just not use fork and exec* inside Boost.Test. Factor these calls out of the units you are testing. After all, a process is not a signle unit, it's more a whole component. I guess you will not have many of those subprocesses, so it should not hurt too much to test the collaboration of those processes with another framework or just a simple script.

Comment: means "maybe with an unbearable amount of work and deep understanding off Boost.Test's internals". Ok, that's probably a "no" for most people, including me ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand execvp() [replaces](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/exec.html) your test program. So Boost.Test is not runing any longer. It only returns in case of failour. I would not use it in this context with Boost.Test.

Comment: I `fork()` before, sorry for not mentioning it